# Is using pytruth considered Pythonic?

Tags: python, unit-testing, coding-style

I recently found Googles [pytruth](https://pypi.org/project/pytruth/) package. I am very used to **pytest** and I am wondering what the value of the way less commonly used `pytruth` is. The only reason why I didn't directly discard it, is that it comes from Google.

From the README, it seems to be mainly (only?) that you have the following ways to write assertions:

```
AssertThat(a).IsEqualTo(b)  # 1
AssertThat(c).IsTrue()  # 2
AssertThat(d).Contains(a)  # 3
AssertThat(d).ContainsAllOf(a, b)  # 4
AssertThat(d).ContainsAnyOf(a, b, c)  # 5
with AssertThat(Error).IsRaised():  # 6
  Explode()
AssertThat(result).ContainsExactlyElementsIn(expected)  # 7
```

I am used to write the following:

```
assert a == b  # 1
assert c  # 2
assert a in d  # 3
for element in [a, b]:  # 4
    assert element in d
assert any(element in d for element in [a, b, c])  # 5
with pytest.raises(Exception):  # 6
    Explode()
assert set(result) == set(expected)  # 7
```

Is there any difference between what I was doing and the `truth` package? Is there any reason to use the truth package? Is it maybe even considered good style?

Comment: One advantage of pytruth over pytest syntax is that its syntax requires less magic than pytest's. Pytest syntax is clean, and its error message introspection is even more awesomer, but it uses deep magic to make it work, which many people are somewhat wary of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which way you find more readable, the pytruth ot the pytest way propably comes down to what you are used to. If you are used ot Java, you will find that more readable.

> It is shared with the community to bring an expressive, consistent assertion style to projects that may be using a combination of unittest, abseil, googletest, mox, and mock—especially to people familiar with Java Truth.

(quoted from the pypilink)

JavaTruth, there we have it. So then, if you have to maintain Java and Python applications, this may be worth it to you for improved consistency.

As far as I see it, pytruth can be used with any testing framework. If you use pytest, you are locked in the whole framework. So if you want something different than pytest, you can use pytruth on top. If you are already bought into pytest, I'd personally  rather prefer the way pytest handles asserts

Answer (score 6):

Some of these, particularly 4, 5 and 7 are "clearly" more readable in the fluent `truth` style - the assertion does *exactly* what it does, no brainpower required.

It is also worth noting that your #7 does not match the `truth` example: think about what happens if `d` contains an element `foo`. Sure, you can fix it, but if you got it wrong writing the question, would you get it wrong writing production code as well?

Comment: I changed 7 - I didn't know what the "Exactly" of `pytruth` does. So this undermines the point that it is more readable.

Comment: But is it really only about readability or does `pytruth` offer something I missed?

Comment: Particularly when it comes to test code, readability is everything. And I still find PyTruth much more readable than `set(a) == set(b)`.

Comment: And note your example 7 is *still* wrong. Consider `result = [1, 2, 1]` and `expected = [1, 2]`.

Comment: For example 7: I think this depends very much on what you want. With `set`, it is clear to me what I get and I would expect those two (`result = [1, 2, 1]` and `expected = [1, 2]`) to be considered the same. result contains the same elements as expected and vice versa. Just not the same amount. From the name `ContainsExactlyElementsIn`, it was not clear to me that this is considered to be different.

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation, PyTruth claims to have more informative failure messages than some other widely-used testing frameworks in Python. (This is of course a subjective measure.)

Failure messages are very important in unit testing, and even more so in Test-Driven Development, where the failure message actually partially drives the implementation. ("Do the simplest thing that could change the failure message.")

Comment: Do you know an example where the error message of pytruth is supposed to be better than the one of pytest?

Comment: Just try your example 7. With raw `assert`: `AssertionError`. With PyTruth: `truth.truth.TruthAssertionError: Not true that <[1, 3]> contains exactly <[1, 2]>. It is missing <[2]> and has unexpected items <[3]>.` That's completely night and day as to clarity, `assert` tells me nothing at all, PyTruth tells me exactly what I need to know.

Comment: I think pytest does give perfectly readable results with the default assert: https://gist.github.com/MartinThoma/62998b958923b0aa4e75adc9984826fd